# A fingerprint reader of Thinkpad E480

Tags: thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I am running Ubuntu 17 on my Thinkpad E480.

I have an external fingerprint reader and would like to know how to use it.

I tried using lsusb, but it didn't show the fingerprint device.

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot showing lsusb and Fingerprint GUI output]

Comment: Where you able to get it working ? I have the same model and didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if you can see your fingerprint device with the next command:

```
lsusb
```

Second, You need to install fingerprint-gui use the next commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

Third, Logout & Login again, launch the Fingerprint GUI and enrol your fingerprints.

Comment: Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:2113 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 17ef:60ac Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Fingerprint GUI 1.09  "No Devices Found"